# Count selected option in combobox

Tags: javascript, php

I need some help in javascript PHP to solve my problem. Please look at my code below:

```
<?PHP
$arrear_per_month = 15000;
?>
<select name="cur_month" id="id_cur_month" multiple="multiple">
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="jan">January</option>
<option value="feb">February</option>
<option value="mar">March</option>
<option value="apr">April</option>
<option value="may">May</option>
<option value="jun">June</option>
<option value="jul">July</option>
<option value="aug">August</option>
<option value="sep">September</option>
<option value="oct">october</option>
<option value="nov">November</option>
<option value="dec">december</option>
</select>

Your current arrear: <input id="id_cur_arrear" type="text" name="arrear" value="" readonly="readonly" />
```

What i want to do is:

1. count how many option is being selected
2. Multiply the number of selected option with $arrear_per_month
3. Display the result in field input as shown above (in arrear)

Example:

1. Let say that February, march and april are selected.
2. So the number of selected option is 3.
3. And then 3 * $arrear_per_month = 45000.
4. So i need to display 45000 as value in arrear
5. [edited] i need to display it without any click (something like onChange)

I think that is what i need, please give me some help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any code you have tried already?

Comment: No there is not. i've tried to googling, but most of them are how to count the value of the selected option, not the number of selected option.

Comment: JavaScript only, 
it was added to the my answer.

Comment: @Bersama I have updated my code for `onchange` event, see if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this via jQuery (with less code). However, if you are specifically looking for JavaScript code, you can try this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function update(){
    var apm = Number("<?php echo $arrear_per_month;?>");
    var cm = document.getElementById("id_cur_month").selectedOptions.length;
    var sel_cnt = (apm * cm);

    document.getElementById("id_cur_arrear").value = sel_cnt;
 }
</script>
```

Add `onchange` event to your `select` box -

```
<select name="cur_month" id="id_cur_month" onchange="update()" multiple="multiple">
```

This will work either you select the options through click or keyboard arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbersChecked = $('#id_cur_month').find(":selected").length;
$("#id_cur_arrear").val(numbersChecked * <?= $arrear_per_mnth; ?>);
```

Comment: You are right it will work, but you have forgotten to mention to use JQuery. Also I'm sure that @Bersama forgot to tell that he needs the selected options which value is not empty.

Comment: Is it really need jquery? so javascript is not enough? @Zeusarm, Yes you right, i forgot it, i dont want to include the empty option, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In javascript this is how you do it

```
var sel = document.getElementById('id_cur_month');
alert(sel.selectedOptions.length);
```

Code above should alert the number of selected options.

However you do need to do some additional coding as you cannot pass a javascript variable to the php code.

You can instead declare that php variable as a javascript variable.

```
<script>
var arrear_per_month = <?php echo $arrear_per_month ?>;
var sel = document.getElementById('id_cur_month');
var total = arrear_permonth * sel.selectedOptions.length;

alert(total);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```
$("#id_cur_month").click(function () {
    var len = 0;
    $("#id_cur_month").children(":selected").each(function () {
        len += ($(this).val() ? 1 : 0);
    });
    var res = len * (parseInt($("#id_cur_arrear").val() || 0));
    $("#id_cur_arrear_res").val(res);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/xu0Lzujj/2/)

**Javascript**

```
var select = document.getElementById("id_cur_month");
console.log(select);
select.onclick = function () {
    var opts = select.options;
    var len = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
        if (opts[i].selected && opts[i].value) len++;
    }
    document.getElementById("id_cur_arrear_res").value = len * (parseInt(document.getElementById("id_cur_arrear").value || 0))
};
```

Use `<?= $arrear_per_mnth; ?>` instance of `(parseInt(document.getElementById("id_cur_arrear").value || 0))`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/xu0Lzujj/5/)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Andrex, i've tried to modify the script like this, but it doesn't work.

```
<?PHP
$arrear_per_month = 15000;
?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var sel = document.getElementById('id_cur_month');
alert(sel.selectedOptions.length);

var arrear_per_month = <?php echo $arrear_per_month ?>;
var sel = document.getElementById('id_cur_month');
var total = arrear_permonth * sel.selectedOptions.length;

alert(total);

document.chk_arrear.arrear.value = total;

</script>
<form name="chk_arrear">
<select name="cur_month" id="id_cur_month" multiple="multiple">
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="jan">January</option>
<option value="feb">February</option>
<option value="mar">March</option>
<option value="apr">April</option>
<option value="may">May</option>
<option value="jun">June</option>
<option value="jul">July</option>
<option value="aug">August</option>
<option value="sep">September</option>
<option value="oct">october</option>
<option value="nov">November</option>
<option value="dec">december</option>
</select>

Your current arrear: <input type="text" name="arrear" value="" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```

the Alert doesnt work and also the input text. Can you please correct this script

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all of you. it's running.

```
<?PHP
$arrear_per_month = 15000;
?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function update(){
var apm = Number("<?php echo $arrear_per_month;?>");
var cm = document.getElementById("id_cur_month").selectedOptions.length;
var sel_cnt = (apm * cm);

document.getElementById("id_cur_arrear").value = sel_cnt;
}
</script>
<form name="chk_arrear">
<select name="cur_month" id="id_cur_month" multiple="multiple" onchange="update()">
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="jan">January</option>
<option value="feb">February</option>
<option value="mar">March</option>
<option value="apr">April</option>
<option value="may">May</option>
<option value="jun">June</option>
<option value="jul">July</option>
<option value="aug">August</option>
<option value="sep">September</option>
<option value="oct">october</option>
<option value="nov">November</option>
<option value="dec">december</option>
</select>

Your current arrear: <input type="text" id="id_cur_arrear" name="arrear" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```